# Googlebot - Not Seeing Mobile Version - Not Mobile Friendly

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, googlebot

I have a website with the Response Header Vary set to "User-Agent". I have verified that none of the JavaScript or CSS code is blocked using the Fetch as Google tool. When looking at the Rendering tab for Googlebot type Mobile:Smartphone it is showing that Googlebot is seeing the normal web version and not the mobile version. It also shows on the Rendering tab that the visitor would have seen the page showing the mobile version correctly.

Google is showing my website as not mobile friendly. But, there is a very nice mobile version of the website for mobile that comes up when I visit with my iPhone or use the Google Chrome simulator. Also, I am not using a second URL for my mobile version (m.mysite.com).

Do I have to convert my website using Bootstrap in order to get Googlebot to see my mobile version and consider my site mobile friendly?

Here are the response Headers:

[image]

The website is built using Sitecore. Here is the rule which sends the Mobile version.

[image]

Comment: Have you run the Mobile Friendly Test and checked the Mobile Usability Report? https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/11/helping-users-find-mobile-friendly-pages.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess that Googlebot is mainly looking if your website is using CSS3 media queries based on the screen width and the meta tag for setting the viewport on mobile devices to decide if a website is mobile friendly or not. I just tested a not even finished layout which is marked as mobile friendly. Also my other sites are all mobile friendly and i never used the user agent to determine how i should render the page, for this I use media queries.

I suggest you, if not already done, adding first the viewport meta tag, and if this doesnt work it MUST work when you switch to using media queries in general and using the user agent only when you want to prevent that media queries are being used. (for example not using the mobile media query when on a desktop)

What you need...

- [Viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) (for example: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`)
- [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

My unfninished layout doesnt even use media queries so i think adding the meta tag is enough. If you want an URL with the code write me a PM.

Comment: The Mobile version does have the <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> tag. It is not there for the desktop version.

Comment: Hmm, do you mind sending me the URL per PM or temporary upload it to a free webspace so we can take a look into it? We can only guess, unless you provide us more informations or the link. Even better would be code that reproduces the situation. And could you try to add the line manually to the head of the desktop version? I highly assume that its this or something with the user agent/media query thingy, because i really didnt take any effort into making my layout "mobile friendly". Just the meta tag is there, but nothing else.

Comment: PM is not possible. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users

Comment: Try to modify the rule so the Googlebot receives the mobile layout. Should be the easiest solution, the better would be to build on media queries but im not sure if this works in your program.